# Adding new columns to this data frame

Tags: r, looper

I have a dataframe like this

```
> dim(anno_maf)
[1] 32786   129
> head(anno_maf[1:2,1:4])
   Tumor_Sample_Barcode Chromosome Start_Position
1:                    a       chr1       27105930
2:                    a       chr1        3342771
   End_Position
1:     27105930
2:      3342771
>
```

I have a list of genes like

```
gene name
PTEN
PTEN
MAP3K1
MALAT1
MED12
RUNX1
PIK3CA
FBXW7
ARID1A
MED12
TAB1
```

I want to add a column in my dataframe named COSMIC, if a gene in gene list exists in my dataframe ***Hugo_Symbol*** column, put a **yes** for this gene if not put a ***no***; Finally my data frame has an extra column as ***COSMIC*** in which I have ***yes*** or ***no*** in ***Hugo_Symbol*** column based on the existence of genes in my gene list

Can you help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse()`:

```
anno_maf$COSMIC <- ifelse(anno_maf$Hugo_Symbol %in% your_gene_list,
                          yes = "yes",
                          no = "no")
```